# Visual Code - Changing project explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

**Q:** Are there ways to change the functionality of the file-explorer in the Visual Code editor?

**Detail:**
I'd like to implement a typical folder structure where you can only ever see the contents of one folder at a time (much like regular folder-navigation in Windows).
So the "root" in the file-explorer in Visual Code would always be the current folder navigated to.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible. You can check all explorer options by entering options (`CTRL` + `,`) and typing in "explorer" in search bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that "can" does not always mean "should", but I believe you "can" accomplish this to a degree. Instead of changing the built in file explorer, though, you'd have to contribute your own "explorer" extension by following the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points#_contributesviews). You specify that you are contributing an explorer in your extension's `package.json` as so:

```
"contributes": {
    "views": {
        "explorer": [
            {
                "id": "myfileexplorer",
                "name": "My File Explorer",
                "when": ""
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You then implement the [TreeDataProvider](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_a-nametreedataprovideraspan-classcodeitem-id1215treedataproviderlttgtspan) interface in your extension.

The process is too involved to describe in a comment here, but you can see sample code [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/tree-view-sample).

Comment: Thank you for a good description and pointer. I kind of expected that an extension would be the way to go, if no "source files" are available for custom builds. I'll mark this as the correct answer, as it concludes the "search".